# Can bounded arithmetic prove prime factorization?

Tags: logic, prime-factorization

I have a simple question.  Can a bounded arithmetic, say $S^1_2$ prove prime factorization?  I think this is an open problem, because if $S^1_2$ can prove prime factorization then prime factorization is $P$, which is open.  But I have a vague recollection that some paper or textbook says prime factorization can be proven by a bounded arithmetic, yet it does not entail prime factorization is $P$.

Is this just my incorrect memory or do you know a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar theorem is Cook and Nguyen, exercise VI.4.4, which is to prove in the system $V_1$ that every binary-encoded integer $X \geq 2$ can be written as a product of primes. This result is from Jerabek's thesis, where he gives a detailed proof in what I take also to be $V_1$.

Part of the exercise is to explain why this doesn't yield a $P$ solution, but to be truthful I am drawing a blank today.

Comment: That is it!  Still puzzled by Jerabek's result, though.